# How to make a line of code execute only after the time interval of the animation block?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

I have put a line of code inside the UIAnimation block. And the next line comes after the animation block. I want the second line only to be executed after the time interval of the first animation block.

Eg:-

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"View Flip" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
//First line comes here
 [self.view addSubview:subView];
 [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Then the 2nd line

```
[subView2 removeFromSuperView];
```

I want the 2nd line only to be executed after the 0.5 second interval of the animation action. Is it possible to do like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a delegate for animation and remove subview in its method:

```
...
[UIView beginAnimations:@"View Flip" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

//First line comes here
[self.view addSubview:subView];
[UIView commitAnimations];
...
```

Then in delegate's animation did stop handler remove your 2nd subview:

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context{
    if ([finished boolValue])
        [subView2 removeFromSuperview];
}
```